# Spring data mongoDb TextCriteria : partial search implemention using springboot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I need to search for documents in a collection named book.

```
@Document(collection="book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private Float page;

    //getters and setters

}

[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55c0e5e5511f0a164a581907"),
        "_class" : "org.packt.model.book",
        "title" : "test with more content",
        "page" : 45
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55c0e5e5511f0a164a581908"),
        "_class" : "org.packt.model.book",
        "title" : "test with less content",
        "page" : 55
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55c0e5e5511f0a164a581909"),
        "_class" : "org.packt.model.book",
        "title" : "test nothing content",
        "page" : 55
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55c0e5e5511f0a164a581910"),
        "_class" : "org.packt.model.book",
        "title" : "A new town",
        "page" : 55
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55c0e5e5511f0a164a581911"),
        "_class" : "org.packt.model.book",
        "title" : "Place of village",
        "page" : 55
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55c0e5e5511f0a164a581912"),
        "_class" : "org.packt.model.book",
        "title" : "tMarcus",
        "page" : 55
    }
]
```

I want when I enter a single character that I can already go back to the result of my search. Then refine the search as the user continues to type their text

If I searching for whole word e.g. "test"  then I am getting the output. Not sure how to implement partial search.